# Describing the set $\{n\in \Bbb N\lvert (n>1)\wedge (\forall x,y\in \Bbb N)[(xy=n)\implies (x=1\lor y=1)]\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, predicate-logic

This set appears in an exercise of the course *Introduction to Mathematical Thinking*, by Dr.Keith Devlin

> $A$=$\{n\in \Bbb N\lvert (n>1)\wedge (\forall x,y\in \Bbb N)[(xy=n)\implies (x=1\lor y=1)]\}$

Although this is the very first question of the exercise on a refresher to Set Theory, I cannot process the logical syntax as it is. I'll break down my approach to understanding this set:

1. The domain of discourse is the set of natural numbers(the convention followed in the course is to exclude $0$ from $\Bbb N$). The set $A$, first and foremost, requires $n$ to be greater than $1$.
2. Next, $A$ requires $n$ to satisfy the implication $(xy=n)\implies (x=1\lor y=1)$ **for every $x, y$ chosen from** $\Bbb N$(this is precisely where I feel I might be wrong).
3. Clearly, in the event of both $x,y$ being greater than 1 the entire implication will be falsified. **Thus, there does not exist any $n\in \Bbb N$ satisfying the conditions required by $A$, which means $A$ is an empty set.**

I'd like to know which part of my reasoning is incorrect(if any at all). I believe such case-by-case splitting may not be necessary for trivial examples like this one (at least for math students and professionals), but I'm a layman and would hence appreciate such an approach.

Comment: $A$ is the set of *prime* numbers

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Please extend your comment as an answer.

Comment: If you were to replace $\implies$ with $\iff$ then it would be an empty set. The thing with $\implies$  is that if we have $False\implies P$, it does not matter if $P$ is true or not, the whole implication is true.

Comment: @Graviton Understood. However, I would still like to see how that leads to the set $A$ being the set of primes.

Comment: Some simple tests to check the meaning of the specifying condition: a) $n=4$; it is greater than 1 but there ara pairs, like e.g $x=y=2$ such that $2 \times 2 =4$ but neither $x$ nor $y$ is equal to $1$. Thus, $4 \notin A$.

Comment: Now repeat the same exercise with $n=5$. There are only two possible choices of $x$ and $y$ that satisfy the condition $xy=5$. See [Prime number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA With some hindsight, I felt it could be the set of primes but the implication and quantifiers perplex me. I've understood your point now, thankyou!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's break it down step by step.

1. You're first point is right, for $n \in A$, $n$ must be an natural number greater than $1$.
2. $n$ must also satify $(xy=n)\implies(x=1\vee y=1)$ for all natural numbers $x$ and $y$, which can be $1$.
3. Now let's look at the general cases for the form of $A\implies B$

If $A$ is **false**, then $(A\implies B)$ is **true**. If $A$ is **true**, then $(A\implies B)$ is **true** **if an only if** $B$ is also **true**.

So now we know that if

$(xy=n)$ is **false** for all natural numbers of $x,y$, then $n\in A$. However, it's very easy to see that it's **not always false**, because if $x=1$ and $y=n$ (which is a perfectly valid possibility!), then $(xy=n)$ is clearly **true**.

What that means is that for the cases where $(xy=n)$ is **true**, we must also have that $(x=1\vee y=1)$ to be **true**. That is the part that restricts $n$ to be a prime number.

I.e; if $n$ is a multiple of two natural numbers $x,y$, it's only prime when for all $x,y$, either $x$ or $y$ is $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Your third point is false. An implication is not necessarily falsified when the conclusion is false.

For instance, (False) $\implies$ (False) is always true.

It might be appropriate to recall the definition : $A \implies B$ holds if, whenever $A$ holds, $B$ holds as well. If $A$ is false, then the implication $A \implies B$ is true, by definition.